# add Pyenv commands to bashrc or zshrc?

Tags: python, bash, shell, zsh, pyenv

This [tutorial](https://akrabat.com/creating-virtual-environments-with-pyenv/) to create virtual environments suggests, that I should add these commands to my `.bashrc` file:

```sh
eval "$(pyenv init -)"
eval "$(pyenv virtualenv-init -)"
```

On the home directory of my macOS, when I check for `ls -a`, I do not see a `.bashrc` file. I do see however a `.zshrc` file. Is this an alternative? Can I put the commands here or should I create a new `.bashrc`file in my home directory using `nano` or similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should run `echo $0` to check which shell you're using, but I would be fairly certain no `.bashrc` means no `bash` shell in use. If you're using a later version of macOS then `zsh` will be in use already as the default shell (but `bash` is in use on older versions pre-Catalina by default).

If `echo $0` *does* output `bash` or `/bin/bash` rather than `zsh` or `/bin/zsh` then you should create a `.bashrc` file and put the commands in it - but if your output contains `zsh`, then you should put the commands in the `.zshrc` file already in existence.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is the file you want to edit if you're on a mac. `.bashrc` is a configuration file for the `bash` shell (an extremely common shell, often assumed to be the ubiquitous shell). This file is sourced every time you start a new shell (running all the commands within). On mac however, the default is `zsh`, which uses `.zshrc` as its configuration file.